# Install4j installer and launcher returns odd errors when Java 9 or 10 are installed

Tags: install4j

We're getting ready to deploy our application (Cytoscape) for Windows, Linux and Mac.

We find that when Java 9 is installed on Fedora 26 64 bit, trying to run the installer gives "JVM must be greater than 1.6", though our JVM range is set to 1.8.0_152...1.9.

**Is there a later installer/launcher version that gives a more informative error message? ... could we have something misconfigured??**

On the same platform, but with Java 10 installed instead, the launcher apparently allows execution to commence (despite our JVM range). This ends badly, as Karaf complains:

```
/opt/Cytoscape_v3.6.1/framework/bin/karaf: line 242: [: : integer expression expected
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/java/jdk-10/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/java/jdk-10/lib/endorsed:/opt/Cytoscape_v3.6.1/framework/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exceThe programmes occurred. Program will exit.
```

**Is the launcher somehow misidentifying the JVM? Shouldn't it give an informative error and stop the launch (including Karaf) from proceeding?**

Thanks!

Comment: `our JVM range is set to 1.8.0_152...1.9` -> There is no version "1.9", the versionig scheme was changed and is now "9", "10", and so on. Also, can you post the entire error message for `"JVM must be greater than 1.6"` or a screen shot of it?

Comment: Thank you. We'll get a screenshot. Meanwhile, I think you're advising that our range should be 1.8.0_152...9 ... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, minimum version 1.8.0_152 and maximum version 9.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the screen shot, we investigated further and found this message coming from Karaf code that didn't anticipate something that's not 1.8. Sorry for the false alarm here, and thanks for your help!